# Electromagnetics scattering

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm interested, what does the Green's function mean in physics of electromagnetic waves.  $g_{0}(\rho-\rho')=\frac{i}{4}H_{0}^{(1)}(k|\rho-\rho'|)$ from: R. F. Harrington, Field Computation by Moment Method, Malabar, FL: Krieger
Publ., 1982.

Comment: Do you understand what a Green’s function is *in general*?

Comment: @G.Smith no, not exactly. can  you explain, or where to find info?

Comment: If you have some linear differential equation with a source term, the Green’s function is the solution for a pointlike source. (A point in space, an instant in time, or both.) You then find the solution for an arbitrary source by superposition. To understand them, you should also understand Dirac delta functions, which describe pointlike sources.

Comment: In your example, $g_0$ probably tells you how a pointlike object scatters a plane wave, or something like that. You can find out how an extended object scatters by doing an integral.

Comment: @G.Smith and can you explain what does the  $\rho$  mean?

Comment: I would guess that it is a cylindrical radial coordinate but since I don’t have the book I can’t be sure. Look earlier in the book to see how it introduces $\rho$. It is almost certainly *not* a charge density.